# Raised bed in citrus cultivation in heavy and low permeable soils

Tags: soil, citrus, irrigation, technique, pomegranate

Good morning, here a citrus grower from Sicily.

Now there is a strong tendency in the world to grow citrus (pomegranates and other plants) in raised beds/berms, like this:

[image: citrus in raised beds]

The reason seems to be that this system greatly increases permeability and aeration in the soil.

The result is that now there are citrus fruits also grown in very clayey areas (> 40%), as it seems that the drainage increases considerably. 10 or 20 years ago, these areas were not considered suitable.

I'm not an agronomist and I don't have a lot of technical expertise, I wanted to understand if anyone has ever measured or if there are studies that have measured the real impact of this system. Are there any improvements on hydraulic conductivity or other significant parameters? 1%? 10%? 50%?